# Loading a dictionary of lists of lists in Unity with Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

So im saving my Dictionary like this:

```
public void saveData()
{
    database.Child("Users").Child("User").SetValueAsync(shoppingList);    
}
```

But if I want to load my dictionary it always returns null when I want to access anything. I load it like this:

```
    public void loadData()
    {

    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Users").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // Handle the error...
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            var result = task.Result;

            var loadedDict = result.Value as Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>;

            Debug.Log(loadedDict);       

            
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what might be happening is that the `var loadedDict = result.Value as Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>;` is not making the conversion rightaway.

I would check the following.

1.- That the data is being properly saved in the save stage, and stored in the database and confirm that in the question.

2.- Even the dictionary is null, check if the data returned from the task is null. Because the data might be being retrieved in the `var result = task.Result;`, but the conversion to the dictionary not working. I would also confirm that in the question if that is the case.

3.- If the data is actually being retrieved in stage 2, and what is not working is the conversion. As far as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot) says, the values returned native types are:

`bool`, `string`, `long`, `double`, `IDictionary{string, object}` and `List{object}`

If you are receiving the data but the `loadedDict` is null, you will need to code the method that converts the `IDictionary{string, object}` to your `Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>` with your info filled in.

I did not use firebase with unity, only in web projects, so I am not sure if this might by your problem, is just my guess. I'll be glad to check what you find out

Comment: Thanks for you answer regarding you questions, the data gets saved correctly, and var is DataSnapshot { key = Users, value = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] } The problem is the conversion i dont know how to do it yet but ill research that.

Comment: isn't this then the answer to your question¿?

Comment: no, bc I need a dictionary of lists which contain lists of strings

Comment: then you should have formulated the question according to that point directly if you knew that already. Your issue has nothing to do with firebase...

Comment: that is a c# question, how to tranform the object you get, to the type you want, nothing to do neither with firebase, nor unity

Comment: Did you read my initial question? Its definitly with unity and firebase and now we solved that and Ican fix the problem we found. Mr Tag Sheriff

Comment: With this : `no, bc I need a dictionary of lists which contain lists of strings ` I understood that you knew the problem from the begging. Nevermind. Good luck!